# POST запрос к контакту

Tags: post, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Приветствую

Начну издалека, есть такая штука unisender - сервис рассылок писем. Там есть API с примерами, называется взял, вставил - вуаля.. И да, в гугле нет такого кол-ва вайна на API юнисендера, в силу примеров для чайников.

Есть контакт, у контакта API, примеров ест-но нет.. эм, есть, размером с дипломную работу с описанием, да еще с 'токенами'.

Еще есть серьезное не понимание самого POST запроса (а еще ведь надо ответ принять) к самому контакту, что не пишется в описании

Может ли кто привести пример ПРОСТОГО POST запроса к контакту, по любому методу, с любым параметром, без токена, с принятием ответа от него?

p.s. контакт, моя больная точка

GET - еще как то понятен, но POST - не в какие ворота,

```
https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uids=1&fields=photo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POST запрос позволяет параметры пихать не в URL, а в тело запроса, вот и почти вся разница с GET'ом.

Для выполнения запросов к api ВКонтакта лучше использовать [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php). POST-данные собираются в один массив, передаваемый через 'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS'.

Вот, набросал [рабочий пример](http://sergeisokolov.com/temp/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$userid = 755074;    // йа, йааа
$method = 'users.get';

$url = sprintf( 'https://api.vk.com/method/%s', $method);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST    => TRUE,            // это именно POST запрос!
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,    // вернуть ответ ВК в переменную
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => FALSE,   // не проверять https сертификаты
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => array(   // здесь параметры запроса:
        'user_id'   => $userid,
    ),
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,    // веб адрес запроса
));

$vk_response = curl_exec($ch); // запрос выполняется и всё возвращает в переменную
curl_close( $ch);

if( $result = json_decode( $vk_response)) { // пробуем распаковать JSON 
    printf('<div>Имя: %s<br />Фамилия: %s</div>', // получилось, выводим ответ
        $result->response[0]->first_name,
        $result->response[0]->last_name
    );
    echo 'Вообще, декодированный ответ ВК выглядит целиком вот так::<br /><pre>' . print_r( $result, TRUE) . '</pre>';
} else {  //  JSON не распаковался
    echo 'VK вернул какой-то не JSON совсем:<br /><pre>' . print_r( $vk_response, TRUE) . '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Ох, вашими бы руками справка к контакту писалась. Не сразу, но врубился во все! Спасибо