# Как поймать запрос?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Уважаемые пользователи прошу от вас помощи, подскажите как поймать запрос или на подобие есть вот ссылка:

```
https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uids=1&fields=photo_big
```

При открытие её там такой код:

```
{"response":[{"uid":1,"first_name":"Павел","last_name":"Дуров","photo_big":"http:\/\/cs7011.vk.me\/c7003\/v7003736\/3a08\/mEqSflTauxA.jpg"}]}
```

Подскажите, как сделать что бы я мог получить `photo_big` и его вставить, у меня вот такой код в php:

```
 <?php
    echo file_get_contents('http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uids=1&fields=photo_big');
?>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас

Comment: А если у меня вот такая ссылка будет ? hhttps://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-460389&count=1&v=5.11  и мне надо получить допустим photo_604

Comment: Разберите ответ, и выведите его, чтобы понять, что там к чему:

    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-460389&count=1&v=5.11';
    $vk_response = file_get_contents( $url);
    $data = json_decode( $vk_response);
    printf( '<pre>%s</pre>',
        print_r( $data, TRUE)
    );

[Работающий пример](http://sergeisokolov.com/temp/vk_test.php)

Значит, надо что-то вроде: 

   $data->response->items[0]->attachments[0]->photo->photo_604

Но не всегда именно так: может не быть приложений, или может быть несколько приложений. Предусматривайте варианты.

Comment: Я в этом не разбираюсь вообще не подскажете как собрать код, и желательно что бы вывод был вот так:
echo $photogru;

Comment: На Хэшкоде не принято делать работу за других. Тут с удовольствием помогают научиться/разобраться. Попробуйте, что именно сейчас вам не понятно?

Comment: Не понятно зачем нужна printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', и как добавить $data->response->items[0]->attachments[0]->photo->photo_604

Comment: и я хотел сделать вывод таким образам: echo $photogru;, потому что у меня будет дальше код вставлен и в нём уже параметр прописан $photogru

Comment: [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php) почти то же, что echo — чтобы вы увидели, что именно отдаёт ВК, **и разобрались**. Вот, выводит url картинки:

    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-460389&count=1&v=5.11';
    $vk_response = file_get_contents( $url);
    $data = json_decode( $vk_response);
    $photogru = $data->response->items[0]->attachments[0]->photo->photo_604;
    echo $photogru;

Answer (score 3):

API ВК возвращает данные в формате [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Их можно распаковать функцией php [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) например, так:

```
$vk_response = file_get_contents('http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uids=1&fields=photo_big');
$data = json_decode( $vk_response);
printf( '<img src="%s" alt="" />',
    $data->response[0]->photo_big
);
```

Это простой, но кривой и не эстетичный способ. По уму надо обращаться к api ВКонтакте с помощью cURL, как я описал в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299771#299812).