# VKontakte API как правильно сформировать POST запрос к методам?

Tags: java, post, vkontakte-api, https

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!

Я так понимаю, ВКонтакте теперь принимает только multipart/form-data?
Помогите его сгенерировать в java?

Я пытаюсь так:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
        multipartEntity.addPart("group_ids", new StringBody("16354654"));

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", multipartEntity.getContentType().getValue());

        try (OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
             InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
             BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            multipartEntity.writeTo(out);

            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }

            return response.toString();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("", e);
    }
```

Получаю уже надоевшую ошибку 100:

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "error_code":100,
        "error_msg":"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: group_ids is undefined",
        "request_params":
        [
            {
                "key":"oauth",
                "value":"1"
            },
            {
                "key":"method",
                "value":"groups.getById"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Пытался и без мультипарт, простым application/x-www-form-urlencoded, запихать строку в тело. Пытался и '&' разделять, и переносом строки - не хочет это хавать ВКонтакт...

Подскажите решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: getById не должен работать по POST вообще, это запрос на получение данных, POST-запросы же отправляют данные. Параметры у вас должны быть не в теле запроса, а в т.н. query string, т.е. в URL.

Comment: Это вы выяснили лично, или так вам показалось? Спрашиваю потому, что документация явно говорит о том, что этот метод можно вызывать, используя POST. Так же, используя POST, у меня получилось вызвать метод из PHP. Проблема именно в составлении в джаве.

Comment: Слушайте, ну я еще раз могу вам повторить ровно то же самое. В документации ничего такого нет, по крайней мере в том английском, на котором она у меня отображается - я думаю, это скорее вам так показалось. В HTTP есть девять методов, и два из них - GET и POST - используются в большинстве случаев для получения и отправки данных соответственно. И еще раз: вам нужно передавать данные не в теле запроса, как сейчас, а в самом URL (т.н. GET-параметры, или, правильнее, query-параметры), можете хоть сами руками этот запрос сложить и в браузере потестировать.

Comment: https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_id=1 если пройдете по этой ссылке, то увидите, насколько мне что-то там кажется (если что, все переходы по ссылкам в браузере - это GET-запросы).

Comment: Хорошо, я всё понимаю. Но вы как раз php занимаетесь - так займитесь вот этим: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299771/post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83 тут cUrl с постом на метод users.get - и он работает. Я даже сниффером его заследил, и он генерит именно пост мультипарт.

Comment: И, да, GET у меня работает, но мне нужен именно POST (для огромных списков этих самых id). Я не совсем новичек, я понимаю разницу между GET и POST. Но тут джава поставила меня раком...

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27022/discussion-between---and-etki).