# Запрос POST к VK.com

Tags: php, кодировка, vkontakte-api

Вопрос к предыдущей теме: [POST запрос к контакту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299771/post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83/486986#486986)

В комментариях к вопросу есть код запроса Имени и фамилии с ВК. 
Вся суть в том, что если имя и фамилия на русском, то выводится следующее:

Имя: РђР»С‘РЅР°
Фамилия: Р§РµСЂРµРїР°РЅРѕРІР°

Вообще, декодированный ответ ВК выглядит целиком вот так:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 99252512
                    [first_name] => РђР»С‘РЅР°
                    [last_name] => Р§РµСЂРµРїР°РЅРѕРІР°
                )
        )
)
```

Как это исправить?

Менял кодировку на windows-1251 и пробовал в других браузерах, но эффект тот же.

Comment: Удостоверьтесь точно, что в настройках браузера стоит кодировка `UTF-8`, а у скрипта `php` cтоит кодировка `UTF-8 без BOM`

Comment: Если открыть в ИЕ и поставить кодировку UTF-8, то не отображаются русские символы вот ссылка на скрин http://s42.radikal.ru/i097/1601/2c/7ba1820cf9ea.png

Comment: Кодировка самого файла `php` какая?

Comment: UTF-8 без BOM .

Comment: Для интереса - можно увидеть скрин этой настройки?

Comment: http://s017.radikal.ru/i413/1601/31/622be3520d0b.png

Comment: Все получилось! В NotePad++ Сделал преобразовать в UTF-8 без ВОМ   Всем спасибо=)

Comment: @Александр По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все получилось! В NotePad++ Сделал преобразовать в UTF-8 без ВОМ Всем спасибо=) –